# How to specify a minimum size of a collectionViews background view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a UICollectionView in several places inside the app and the size of the collectionView is not always the same. I also want to add a backgroundView to my collectionView, so I set it to the backgroundView property of the collectionView. 
This view is also resized when the collectionViews bounds change, which is really nice. But if the collectionView is very small it might be too small for the background view I am using. Is there any way to specify a minimum size (or just height in my case) for the background view? It is ok for the collectionView to be resized even smaller, but the background view should not be shrinked more than that size.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something like `if collectionView.backgroundView.frame.size.height < minimumHeight {
  collectionView.backgroundView.frame.size.height = minimumHeight
}`?

Comment: Since the background view is resized automatically when changing the collectionViews size, this does not bring the effect :/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want a subclass of UIView with your collectionView.

```
class CustomCollectionView : UIView {
    let minimumHeight = 100 //Change this to your needs
    var collectionView = CollectionView() {
       didSet {
           if collectionView.frame.size.height < minimumHeight { 
              self.frame = collectionView.frame
              self.frame.size.height = minimumHeight 
           } else {
              self.frame.size.height = collectionView.frame
           }
        }
    }
    init (collectionView : collectionView) { //Init with custom collectionView
        self.collectionView = collectionView //This will call didSet and set the frame.
        super.init(frame: self.frame)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using didSet means everytime you set a new collectionView to this class, the frame will adjust likewise. You want to make sure you add collectionView as a subView and set its frame / constraints as well within your custom class.

Comment: The frame of the collectionView is being resized, in your example the frame would only be updated once. And why is the collectionView being initialized and in the init overridden?
Also: With that wrapper I would have to redirect the delegate and dataSource and all layout tasks through this view class which does not make sense.